# Limitar valor R$ em campo input com HTML5 e CSS3 com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Preciso limitar o valor em R$ de campo input de um formulário. O formulário está assim:

```
<div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dinheiro"><b>Desejo doar em R$: </label>
                    <input name="campo1" onkeypress="mascara(this,mreais)" size="7" min="10,00" max="1.064,00" /><br>                    
                    <small>Conforme resolução do TSE, as doações são limitadas a R$ 1.064,10 por dia e a 10% dos rendimentos brutos em 2017 para cada pré-candidato. </small><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-doar-form">Doar com Pagseguro</button>           
                   <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn-doar-form">Doar com PayPal</button> -->

                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

E fiz um script para atribuir R$ no campo assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function mascara(o, f) {
                v_obj = o
                v_fun = f
                setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
            }

            function execmascara() {
                v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
            }

            function mreais(v) {
                v = v.replace(/\D/g, "") //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
                v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/, ",$1") //Coloca a virgula
                v = v.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3},\d{2})$/g, "$1.$2") //Coloca o primeiro ponto
                return v
            }
        </script>
```

Como posso limitar o valor máximo em R$ 1.064,00?

Comment: O max, se vc colocar apenas "1064" nao funciona?

Comment: Não. Ai permite 1064 caracteres...

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo, em 1065 ele reclamou: "Please enter a value less than or equal to 1064."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode também restringir os valores usando este código no final da função `mreais(v)`:

```
function mreais(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "") //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/, ",$1") //Coloca a virgula
    v = v.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3},\d{2})$/g, "$1.$2") //Coloca o primeiro ponto

   if(v.length >= 5){
      var maximo = v.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.') > 1064;
      var minimo = v.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.') < 10;

      if(maximo){
         return '1.064,00';
      }else if(minimo){
         return '10,00';
      }else{
         return v;
      }
   }else{
      return v;
   }
}
```

Você pode remover os atributos `min` e `max` do `input` porque só funcionam em `type="number"`. A propósito, a sua máscara não irá funcionar em `input` `type="number"`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function mascara(o, f) {
    v_obj = o
    v_fun = f
    setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
}

function execmascara() {
    v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function mreais(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "") //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/, ",$1") //Coloca a virgula
    v = v.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3},\d{2})$/g, "$1.$2") //Coloca o primeiro ponto
   
   if(v.length >= 5){
      var maximo = v.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.') > 1064;
      var minimo = v.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.') < 10;

      if(maximo){
         return '1.064,00';
      }else if(minimo){
         return '10,00';
      }else{
         return v;
      }
   }else{
      return v;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <form>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="dinheiro"><b>Desejo doar em R$: </label>
           <input name="campo1" onkeypress="mascara(this,mreais)" size="7" /><br>                    
           <small>Conforme resolução do TSE, as doações são limitadas a R$ 1.064,10 por dia e a 10% dos rendimentos brutos em 2017 para cada pré-candidato. </small><br>
           <button type="submit" class="btn-doar-form">Doar com Pagseguro</button>           
          <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn-doar-form">Doar com PayPal</button> -->

       </div>

   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fazendo um teste simples aqui, com o input abaixo:

```
<input type = "number" min= '10' max = '1064'>
```

Automáticamente, ao digitar 1065 tive o retorno abaixo:

> Please enter a value less than or equal to 1064

Note que o min e max tem que ser inteiros (não se referem ao número de caracteres mas sim ao tamanho do número permitido). Caso precise que seja quebrado o número, use a opção `step = 0.01`